# Как правильно выполнить типизацию функции трансформации данных?

Tags: typescript

Всем привет, у меня есть функция трансформации данных:

```
const orders = [
    {
        "date": "2017-10-16 12:07:07",
        "docTypesName": "Приход",
        "docId": 564564867361367,
        "image": "https://www.komus.ru/medias/sys_master/root/hd3/h93/9286922043422.jpg",
        "name": "Молочный Изюм 100",
        "price": 102,
        "quantity": 45,
        "removed": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-10-16 12:07:07",
        "docTypesName": "Приход",
        "docId": 564564867361367,
        "image": "https://mariupolcena.com/files/products/9ff44136e6ccb0afb404ad26f727e67d.jpeg",
        "name": "Русская картошка чедар 50",
        "price": 46.3,
        "quantity": 45,
        "removed": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-10-16 12:07:07",
        "docTypesName": "Расход",
        "docId": 564564867361367,
        "image": "https://mariupolcena.com/files/products/9ff44136e6ccb0afb404ad26f727e67d.jpeg",
        "name": "Русская картошка чедар 50",
        "price": 46.3,
        "quantity": 45,
        "removed": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-11-29 17:26:57",
        "docTypesName": "Расход",
        "docId": 564564867361365,
        "image": "https://www.komus.ru/medias/sys_master/root/hd3/h93/9286922043422.jpg",
        "name": "Молочный Изюм 100",
        "price": 102,
        "quantity": 6,
        "removed": 0
    },
]

interface IOrder {
    date: string,
    docTypesName: string,
    docId: number,
    image: string,
    name: string,
    price: number,
    quantity: number,
    removed: number,
}

interface  IProduct {
    image: string,
    name: string,
    price: number,
    quantity: number,
}

interface IDocument {
    date: string,
    docId: number,
    docTypesName: string,
    products: IProduct[],
}

interface IElement {
    date: string,
    documents: IDocument[]
}

interface IResult {
    '2017-10-16': IElement,
}

function f(orders: IOrder[]) {
    const result: IElement = orders.reduce((accumulator: any, currentValue: IOrder) => {
        const date = currentValue.date.split(' ')[0];

        if (!accumulator[date]) {
            accumulator[date] = {
                date,
                documents: {},
            }
        }

        if (!accumulator[date].documents[currentValue.docTypesName]) {
            accumulator[date].documents[currentValue.docTypesName] = {
                date: currentValue.date,
                docId: currentValue.docId,
                docTypesName: currentValue.docTypesName,
                products: [],
            }
        }

        accumulator[date].documents[currentValue.docTypesName].products.push({
            name: currentValue.name,
            price: currentValue.price,
            image: currentValue.image,
            qunatity: currentValue.quantity,
        })

        return accumulator;
    }, {})
    console.log('result', result);

    return Object.values(result).map((currentValue: IElement) => {

        console.log('currentValue', currentValue);

        if (currentValue.documents) {
            currentValue.documents = Object.values(currentValue.documents);
        }

        return currentValue;
    });
}

console.log(f(orders));
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как более правильно описать типизацию и
как правильно типизировать вот этот момент, соответственно избавиться от any?

```
const result: IElement = orders.reduce((accumulator: any, currentValue: IOrder) => {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типизированный код без единого приведения типов или `any`:

```
const orders = [
    {
        "date": "2017-10-16 12:07:07",
        "docTypesName": "Приход",
        "docId": 564564867361367,
        "image": "https://www.komus.ru/medias/sys_master/root/hd3/h93/9286922043422.jpg",
        "name": "Молочный Изюм 100",
        "price": 102,
        "quantity": 45,
        "removed": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-10-16 12:07:07",
        "docTypesName": "Приход",
        "docId": 564564867361367,
        "image": "https://mariupolcena.com/files/products/9ff44136e6ccb0afb404ad26f727e67d.jpeg",
        "name": "Русская картошка чедар 50",
        "price": 46.3,
        "quantity": 45,
        "removed": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-10-16 12:07:07",
        "docTypesName": "Расход",
        "docId": 564564867361367,
        "image": "https://mariupolcena.com/files/products/9ff44136e6ccb0afb404ad26f727e67d.jpeg",
        "name": "Русская картошка чедар 50",
        "price": 46.3,
        "quantity": 45,
        "removed": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-11-29 17:26:57",
        "docTypesName": "Расход",
        "docId": 564564867361365,
        "image": "https://www.komus.ru/medias/sys_master/root/hd3/h93/9286922043422.jpg",
        "name": "Молочный Изюм 100",
        "price": 102,
        "quantity": 6,
        "removed": 0
    },
]

interface IOrder {
    date: string,
    docTypesName: string,
    docId: number,
    image: string,
    name: string,
    price: number,
    quantity: number,
    removed: number,
}

interface  IProduct {
    image: string,
    name: string,
    price: number,
    quantity: number,
}

interface IDocument {
    date: string,
    docId: number,
    docTypesName: string,
    products: IProduct[],
}

interface IElement {
    date: string,
    documents: IDocument[]
}

interface AccumulatorItem {
  date: string;
  documents: Record<string, IDocument>
}

type Accumulator = Record<string, AccumulatorItem>

function f(orders: IOrder[]): IElement[] {
    const result = orders.reduce<Accumulator>((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        const date = currentValue.date.split(' ')[0];

        if (!accumulator[date]) {
            accumulator[date] = {
                date,
                documents: {},
            }
        }

        if (!accumulator[date].documents[currentValue.docTypesName]) {
            accumulator[date].documents[currentValue.docTypesName] = {
                date: currentValue.date,
                docId: currentValue.docId,
                docTypesName: currentValue.docTypesName,
                products: [],
            }
        }

        accumulator[date].documents[currentValue.docTypesName].products.push({
            name: currentValue.name,
            price: currentValue.price,
            image: currentValue.image,
            quantity: currentValue.quantity,
        })

        return accumulator;
    }, {})

    console.log('result', result);

    return Object.values(result).map((currentValue) => {
        console.log('currentValue', currentValue);

        return {
          ...currentValue,
          documents: Object.values(currentValue.documents),
        }
    });
}

console.log(f(orders));
```

Comment: отличное решение, но в этом случае я бы всё же переименовал `const result` на что-то вроде `accumulator`

Comment: @qwabra согласен, но я только поправил типы, как просил автор, сам код я не менял :)

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, как ... избавиться от any?

Да очень просто:

```
const result: IElement = orders.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => null as any, {} as IElement)
```

---

## Полное решение для частного случая

[песочница там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFHATgEwKboM4BciAkgHQDyWuA2gLoCURZAhhBCALYgA2zUGAHgBEAISEA%20RAG8AsAChEiCAjxRErdl1790TUhs48%20goQEEJiALyIMOfKXTZMICNhQoDW4%20gA0SkOiOYFAAaszcINiMJPpshtom5pKWkrIKikoqaph82Fb%20gdjBYRHYpDlQZXgADtwwUCgA5IiN9NQADLTy8hmIMMCIKACEnkY61BXYDNI9vepxXuOTtPlpcxmTPrPrmHCaRVCE0gC%20W%20m9x9uIl%20eZYKqIu-vBePmjCegTubTle5wHeG6t36gyGT3%20L2o7EKxXCkV%20EAAKgBParYPAAOWYHCm9Bmt0U4JxkOhQVCcLKTxRaMx2KmqyuvUmRFJBxK8M2jI2e2ImBZATJ7MpPMwZ3WhL21PRWJx-Jh5NKCKltJxYvF1XQcGc0COdDVFyuN16ynuaikiDAdL8Gpgrj8MA4zAA5tg-ABHEDMYL1ZHXfKs2GlIFMv7Ew5QgVsilK1HSuldAmIUgarUuQ7JkB4AAWKHNltViBtdr6jpd7s93qgvuO9GDGUcUACSHe3lmpxO6leLAWY0SElrclmJrwcG4ZW4cCdTUceB4UEafhbOgHswbTcQUHQXrwwAwHA8PY%20A5u8lAkFgCA3W-uu-Q%206XGD0D-QwiS0W7ml7L9EFjWdweM5zk%20h7eMIYjJPMn4fJ26hgMida3oMY5qAA1tgvowM2IHLvivSAdwUDUGhyI-ESAL5OQABGABW2DQKQABuFJ4AeUHeER6GkaGAIDooRqIGu6BIPhUDyCecj5ui1SsHkxC4Yg2AAB7VBgaiYZU6DADJiAAKJjmG8mErkRCqOgmFOvqjzcS8RAACLWYRCZ8bMSkqeganBLgWmuIg9nPGaVzMrp%20kHNQjSTI0tCWU8vJEGAnCUbg0WSrGKrYCZm7mZZKbaocRAAAqarlepti5ymqX0nmadphWptAhkls66WIKZWVXJJGVmWAFlXEWzXxRwiW%20FcHperAVZxQlSWlekAD0s2IIAQiCAAwggBcIIggC8IIArCCIIAAiDLYAjCCAHwgK1bYtiAANwoLM80KeV7mVRp3l5JQdh3ZUYCYK8tW5e9RRfYg5AcPUAh%20RCUB%20I0OVpngjSpDdC2KI4HBwAxTiTYN01zQt-GuRVVZooDVDoPkP1pogABkgPA1AoMOZD0M6nDlMNcjqPoxaU3Dek4mKHjD2STU2nPg1-NqATeRkS8JSvNYXrInQVxixusZWf5suIAASnRth0-5YVUqlMrYJFfhg2G4gzXz93i6rz4CIif2fa8ZhCIgAA%20iA-hB2vKFgAitd1fh-kZlSdW1txS3liCO0pH0A67iAAPyQfE3gIuDrxEPLis85bcg3EAA)

```
function f(orders: I.Order[]): I.accumulator<"B"> {
  const accumulator: I.accumulator<"A"> = orders.reduce((accumulator, currentValue): I.accumulator<"A"> => {
    const date = currentValue.date.split(' ')[0]

    if (!accumulator[date]) {
      accumulator[date] = {
        date,
        documents: {},
      }
    }
    const documents = accumulator[date].documents

    if (!documents[currentValue.docTypesName]) {
      documents[currentValue.docTypesName] = {
        date: currentValue.date,
        docId: currentValue.docId,
        docTypesName: currentValue.docTypesName,
        products: [],
      }
    }
    const { name, price, image, quantity } = currentValue

    documents[currentValue.docTypesName]
      .products.push({ name, price, image, quantity })

    return accumulator
  }, {} as I.accumulator<"A">)

  console.log('result', accumulator)

  return transform(accumulator)
}

function transform(accumulator: I.accumulator<"A">): I.accumulator<"B"> {
  const result: I.accumulator<"B"> = accumulator as any

  for (let key in accumulator) {
    result[key].documents = Object.values(accumulator[key].documents)
  }
  return result
}

namespace I {
  export interface Element {
    date: string,
    documents: Document[]
  }
  export interface Document {
    date: Element['date'],
    docId: number,
    docTypesName: string,
    products: Product[],
  }
  export interface Product {
    image: string,
    name: string,
    price: number,
    quantity: number,
  }
  // так не работает ;(
  // export interface Order extends Product extends Omit<Document, 'products'> {
  //   removed: number,
  // }
  export type Order = Product & Omit<Document, 'products'> & {
    removed: number,
  }

  export namespace accumulator {
    export type documentsVals = any[]
    export type documents = Record<Document['docTypesName'], Document>
  }
  export type accumulator<T extends "A" | "B"> = Record<string, {
    date: string,
    documents: T extends "A" ? accumulator.documents : any[]
  }>
}
```

тут обнаружилась ошибка

```
documents[currentValue.docTypesName].products.push({
  name: currentValue.name,
  price: currentValue.price,
  image: currentValue.image,
  //FIXME: qunatity !== quantity
  qunatity: currentValue.quantity,
})
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но было стремление прийти к тому, чтобы совсем не использовать ключевое слово any.

Comment: А где у меня any